# Pandoc LatTeX to word, `scriptsize` commands cause errors

Tags: pandoc

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
we have $\sigma_V$, $\sigma_\text{V}$, but $\sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}$
\end{document}
```

This produces a warning (using `pandoc.exe .\mwe.tex -o mwe.docx`,

```
    [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math \sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}, rendering as TeX:
    \sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}
                 ^
    unexpected "\\"
    expecting "}", text, "{", "$", "$$", "\\(" or "\\["
```

Correspondingly, the docx output is
[image]

Now, in [Pandoc LaTeX to .docx, change font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369424/pandoc-latex-to-docx-change-font-size) the answer states that pandoc doesn't recognise `\scriptsize` (and other) commands. Is there a way to

1. make pandoc understand those,  or
2. make pandoc ignore them?

(In my application, the font size commands show up mostly in subscripts. Ignoring them which is something I could live with for the word output, whcih is for sharing with colleagues, but not in the LaTeX source. If it helps, most instances of the form `\sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}` appear in defined `\newcommands`, so maybe pandoc can use its own newcomamnds without the `\scriptsize`(?).)

Comment: `\sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}` is (1) dangerous andf (2) `\scriptsize` is a math command and the argument to `\text` is text not math. `\sigma_{v}` would give the same. `a_\text{...}` is just plain wrong and should never be used. It is pure change that it actually works.

Comment: s/change/chance/ ?

Comment: @daleif (1) why is it dangerous? (2)`\scriptsize` is text mode command (unlike `\scriptstyle`), and `the output of  `\sigma_\text{\scriptsize v}` is obviously different from  \sigma_v`. (3) What is wrong about `a_\text{...}`?

Comment: there is no reason to expect `x_\text{...}`to work, it does due to low level parsing weirdness if you use a full tex parser but it is not latex syntax, it shoud be `x_{\text{...}}`  also `x_{\mathrm{...}}` is almost always preferable as it uses the fonts specified for math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK; good to know; I have been using `x_\text{...}` since forever. Should I expect it to stop working at any point? (I would have to rewrite all my old files...)

Comment: @Toffomat unfortunately we probably can not make it stop working even though it has never been supported and is just such a weird syntax. Several latex to whatever convertors fail on it.  Any reasonable parser would have `_` parse like a macro argument `\fbox\text{x}` is `\fbox{\text}{x}` and an error. `_\text{x}` is not `_{\text}{x}` it magically braces itself and  expands to `_{\text{x}}` and "works" but if you have that in a document I'd use an editor to fix the markup.

Comment: `sed -i '' s/_\\text/_\\mathrm/g *.tex`  ?

Comment: @Thruston I want to keep the `text`, but would have to add curly braces around the subscript. If I have to, I will try to cook up a regular expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you *want* upright roman subscripts, then it would be better to say so explicitly in the markup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
we have $\sigma_V$, $\sigma_{\mathrm{V}}$, but $\sigma_{\mathrm{v}}$
\end{document}
```

This produces exactly the same PDF as the MWE, but also seems to work ok with Pandoc.

To get even smaller subscripts, then stick with math sizing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
we have $\sigma_V$, $\sigma_{\mathrm{V}}$, but $\sigma_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{v}}$
\end{document}
```

This also appears to work with Pandoc.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work: I want *smaller* upright roman subscripts. The `\text{...}` command works fine, it is the `\scriptsize` that causes the problem (also inside `\mathrm{}`).

Comment: See edits to answer

Comment: @Toffomat `\text` is the wrong markup if you want upright roman, it gives you the current _text_ font active before the math started, so for example it is typically italic if the math is in a theorem. If you do use `\text` in a subscript , it is automatically scriptsize, so `\scriptsize` does nothing

Comment: It is still wrong to write `v\sigma_\mathrm{v}`, as David mentions there is no reason for it to keep working, please always use `\sigma_{\mathrm{v}}` then inexperienced users don't get into bad habits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, I missed that it's automatically `scriptsize`, but the problem is the same with `\tiny`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was also a bit sloppy: I do want the subscript in the curent text font. In particular, on a slide I would want the subscript in sans (as the text is). So `\text{}`works better for me than `\mathrm{}`

Comment: In any case, the answer solves the problem in

Comment: @Toffomat use math commands for fonts in math, so `\mathrm` and if you must, `\scriptscriptstyle` as in the answer here. `\tiny` is a _text_ font command

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there anything technically wrong with `$x \text{a\tiny b} y$`? (I'm regularly using stuff like `\epsilon_{\text{\tiny M}}` because uper case subsripts are too big for lower case Greek letters.)

Comment: It is logically dubious to be using text fonts. In the default setup it happens that the roman math font is the text font but they are declared separately and not necessarily the same. It's also somewhat inefficient as `\text` has to switch out of math, typeset the content in 4 styles, then pick the style needed and insert in to the math list. @Toffomat

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my view, the subscripts which are not mathematical (i.e. stuff like k_effective, M_Planck etc as opposed to indices, powers, transpose etc.) feel texty, so I'd like them to be e.g. sans-serif if the text is, and switching between e.g. `\mathsf` and `\mathrm` is cumbersome and error-prone. So `\text`does exactly what I need -- is  there a way that is more in line with LaTeX internal structure?